# o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor: The host [${ip}] is not valid

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I've noticed the following entry in the log of a Spring Boot application. What does it mean?

```
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]: 2022-08-03 23:52:59.388  INFO 227020 --- [io-8082-exec-23] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : The host [${ip}] is not valid
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:  Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:298) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:807) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
Aug 03 23:52:59 java[227020]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `host` field in the header of the http request you sent does not resolve `${ip}` correctly, please check the information of the request you sent.

Comment: Thanks @Aooohan. so this means that some guy or script on the internet has sent me an HTTP request with setting the host header field?

Comment: Yes, and the value of the host is ${ip} which is not a correct.